# Hover or mouseover on youtube embedded player

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have an embedded youtube player and I would like to trigger some actions when a user hovers the mouse over the player or leaves the player.  I cannot seem to make this happen.

```
<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    });
  }
  $('#ytplayer').hover(
    function() {
        alert('hover');
    },
    function() {
      alert('hover out');
    }
   );
  $('#ytplayer').mouseover(
    function() {
      alert('mouseover');
    }
  )
</script>
<body>
<div id="ytplayer"></div>

</body>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TPTb9/

I also tried to create a div covering the player but that did not seem to work either.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FDt44/1/

Having the cover div over the youtube player prevents any mouse actions making it to the player it seems.  I thought this was due to my z-index parameters.  However, when setting the 'ytplayer' div to z-index 20 and the 'cover' div to 10, this still occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look now at your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TPTb9/3/

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#ytplayer').hover(
function() {
    alert('hover');
},
function() {
  alert('hover out');
}
);
})
</script>
```

Comment: Why does this work?  I had a hunch that it might have had something to with the timing and building of the youtube object on page load?

Comment: nothing like that as far as I know you were not calling the functions on document ready. Its like binding the functions before the actual element exists in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue with mouseenter on a embedded YouTube Iframe. In my case (only in Firefox) the mouseenter event on the Iframe was only fired once. Maybe this has something to do with the focus.

I solved this by adding a small padding border of 10px around the Iframe. This way the mouse enters the Iframe element before the embedded video and the event always fires.

CSS:

```
.YoutubeIframe{
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
height: 157px;
width: 280px;
```

}

Javascript bind:

```
function bindYouTubeVideoMouseEnter(){
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".YoutubeIframe", function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
 });
}

function bindYouTubeVideoMouseLeave(){
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".YoutubeIframe", function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by create div over Youtube

```
  function createMouseMoveCatcher(){
    mouseMoveCatcher = document.createElement('div');
    mouseMoveCatcher.className = 'uppod-mouse-move-catcher'
    CSS(mouseMoveCatcher, {
      display: 'none',
      'z-index': '103',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '0px',
      left: '0px',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
    });
    document.body.appendChild(mouseMoveCatcher);
  }
```

And then

```
document.body.onmousemove = function(){ console.log(1); };
```